# NSURL Session и сохранение данных

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, сессия

Загружаю данные в загрузке экрана(viewDidLoad). Все попытки сохранения полученных данных данных безуспешны: если добавлять через addObject, массив остается пустой(выводит nil), хотя данные которые пытаемся туда добавить - существуют(выводит данные)
id object - хранит в себе все данные в полной мере(их можно вывести), но как только выходим из тела этого запроса, данные исчезают(переменная класса testIdData - пуст после тела запроса, а в теле с данными).
В общем глупый вопрос, но как мне вытащить эти данные за пределы тела?
На входе данные JSON

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
tableViewData = [NSMutableArray new];
// создаем запрос
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]; // URL
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                              {
                                                  if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && error == nil){

                                                      //id object2 = [tableViewData objectAtIndex:0];
                                                      id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                                      [_tableViewData addObject:object];
                                                      NSLog(@"%@",tableViewData);
                                                      // Скриншот результата 1   
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }];
    [downloadTask resume];
    NSLog(@"%@",tableViewData); // Скриншот результата 2
```

Переменные класса viewController, в котором находится запрос

```
@interface ViewControllerTable : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
}
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *tableViewData;
```

Скриншот 1[image: Скриншот 1]

Скриншот 2

[image: Скриншот 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы не инитиализируете массив. Прежде чем добавлять в массив элементы вы должны его инитиализировать: `tableViewData = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: пытался добавить через addObject:object и через addObject:data, внутри тела данные у tableViewData теперь есть, за пределами - массив пустой(уже не nil, а пустые скобки)

Comment: Где Вы инитиализируете массив? В completionHandler блоке?

Comment: внутри viewDidLoad (загрузки экрана)

Comment: Вы уверены, что проверяете массив на наличие элементов, после того, как они туда добавляются?

Comment: Еще как вариант, можете попробовать сделать так: при объявлении переменной добавить __block и у вас получиться __block NSMutableArray *tableViewData;

Comment: Добавление _block не помогло, добавил скриншоты, что хранит в себе внутри блока и что вне

Comment: Блок выполняется асинхронно, возможно информация в лог выводиться до того, как завершен блок. Проверьте значение массива в методе ViewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

Переменная объявлена через @property? Установите флаг strong вместо weak.

> Атрибут weak используется обычно только для делегатов, так как при каждом вхождении он обнуляет цепи ссылок на объект, а с атрибутом strong такого не случится, он указывает что это сильная ссылка, цепь не рушится и переменная не об nil'яется.

Comment: Код изменил, не помогло, добавил скриншоты

Comment: @StriBog, все верно, блок ответа от dataTaskWithURL выполняется позже логирования (скриншот 2), на момент его вывода данные не получены с сервера, то есть сначала у вас в логе появится скриншот 2, затем скриншот 1. Следует выполнять работу над массивом внутри блока ответа dataTaskWithURL